# find the difference of two files and append to the first file powershell

Tags: powershell

file1.txt has

```
line1
line2
line3
```

file2.txt has

```
line2
line4
line5
line6
```

to compare and find difference and write to file3.txt :

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content file1.txt ) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content file2.txt ) -PassThru | Out-File file3.txt

#append the difference to add to file1:
$From = Get-Content -Path .\file3.txt
Add-Content -Path .\file1.txt -Value $From
```

when i do above i get below output:

```
line1
line2
line3line1
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

expected output in file1.txt is

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

Comment: How about `Get-Content -Path .\file*.txt | Select-Object -Unique`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if files are small, the following would work for you

```
$file1 = Get-Content file1.txt
$file2 = Get-Content file2.txt
$file3 = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $file1 -DifferenceObject $file2 -PassThru | where SideIndicator -ne '<='

Out-File -InputObject ($file1 + $file3) -FilePath .\file1.txt
```